# Fetch data by percent from sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named categories which has near about 24 categories and each category has a percent value like 20, 10, 5. I have an another table with near about 10 millions records in it. each record has a categoryid belongs to category table. I need to fetch data from second table according to the percent given in category table. I have done this job using cursor but as cursor scans each record, it is taking near about three minutes to retrieve records from second table. Is there any way to fetch records from second table using joins. Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NTILE(**100**)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) function in MSSQL to distribute rows in each category to 100 groups. Following query will work correctly if each group has at least 100 records:

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff521/1)</kbd>

```
Select T.* from categories
JOIN
( select TData.*,
         NTILE(100) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY TData.CategoryID ORDER BY TData.Id) as Grp
from TData
) as T
      on (T.categoryId=categories.id)
          AND
         (T.Grp<=Categories.PercentOfRecords)
ORDER BY T.CategoryId,T.Id
```